# What´s wrong in my query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that I can get right. So here is my scenario:
I have 1 parent table called 'Couriers', then 1 courier may have 1 or many 'Messengers' then Couriers has a 2nd table called 'Control' where I control how many messengers can a courier have.
The structures goes like this:

```
'Courier'
idCourier(pk)
181
162
101
'Messenger'
idMessenger (pk), idCourier (fk)
1                 101
2                 181
3                 101
4                 101
5                 162

'Control'
idCourier(pk, fk), maxNumberOfMessengers, idSupervisor
181                20                     146
181                20                     149
162                10                     129
162                10                     130
162                10                     138
162                10                     139
101                0                      83
101                0                      86
```

So with the next query:

```
SELECT COUNT(G.idCourier) AS NUM_COURIER, G.idMessenger, SUM(T.maxNumberOfMessengers) AS TOTAL
FROM Courier M
LEFT JOIN Messenger G ON M.idCourier = G.idCourier 
LEFT JOIN Control T ON T.idCourier = G.idCourier AND T.idCourier = M.idCourier
GROUP BY G.idMessenger
```

I get:

```
NUM_COURIER   G.idMessenger  TOTAL
2             181             40
4             162             40
6             101             0
```

And I was expecting:

```
NUM_COURIER   G.idMessenger  TOTAL
1             181             40
3             162             40
1             101             0
```

What am I missing or doing wrong in my query???
Thanks in advance!!:)

Comment: Are you using mysql? SQL server? Oracle?

Comment: I think you don't need to LEFT JOIN the tables but rather INNER JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many messengers do we have per courier?

```
SELECT idCourier, COUNT(*) CourierCount FROM Messenger GROUP BY idCourier
```

Now join this and compare to control:

```
SELECT CO.idcourier, 
       CO.maxnumberofmessengers, 
       CC.couriercount 
FROM   control CO 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT idcourier, 
                          Count(*) CourierCount 
                  FROM   messenger 
                  GROUP  BY idcourier) CC 
               ON CC.idcourier = CO.idcourier
```

Comment: almost perfect, it´s missing the sum in maxNumberOfMessengers and a group by idCourier and courierCount

Comment: If `idCourier` is PK as you have indicated in your post then no sum is required, as it is unique. From your data sample `idCourier` is _not_ unique but your table definition says it is. If this is the case you have a data modelling issue as a single courier could have a few different `maxNumberOfMessengers` defined. If you need a `SUM` as you say then that implies that each courier/supervisor component just makes up a segment of the total `maxNumberOfMessengers`

Answer (score 0):

My previous query incorrectly assumed that we needed to count the number of courier entries in the Control table, while also summing the number of messengers.

```
    SELECT COUNT(T.idCourier) AS NUM_COURIER, T.idCourier, SUM(T.maxNumberOfMessengers) AS TOTAL
    FROM Control T
    GROUP BY T.idCourier
```

I see now that we need to get the number of Messengers. So a sub query is required:

```
    SELECT Couriers.CourierCount as NUM_COURIER, Couriers.idCourier, MaxMessengers.TOTAL
    FROM 
    (SELECT M.idCourier, COUNT(*) CourierCount FROM Messenger M GROUP BY M.idCourier) Couriers
    JOIN(SELECT C.idCourier, SUM(C.maxNumberOfMessengers) AS TOTAL From Control C GROUP BY C.idCourier) MaxMessengers
    ON MaxMessengers.idCourier = Couriers.idCourier
```

Comment: counting and grouping on the same field doesn't work very well. changing from outer to inner join will not stop it double counting.

Comment: You were right about the outer join, I've removed that. I didn't realize counting and grouping on the same field doesn't work well; it seems to work for me, though I'm using SQL Server and not Oracle. Do you know why this is problematic?

Comment: Apologies, it was a throwaway comment - I don't know if an error occurs or not but it is a logical issue. Logically you are either grouping or aggregating a column, but never both.

Comment: For the record it works fine in Oracle but logically it makes no sense. Counting and aggregating on a field is the same as just grouping on the field, so the aggregate is redundant and misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Oracle so I hope this is helpful as this is how you would do this with MS Sql.

```
SELECT COUNT(G.idCourier) AS NUM_COURIER,
m.idcourier,
(
SELECT sum(maxnumberofmessengers)
FROM CONTROL con
WHERE con.idcourier = m.idcourier
GROUP BY con.idcourier
) AS TOTAL
FROM Courier M
JOIN Messenger G ON M.idCourier = G.idCourier
GROUP BY m.idcourier
```

Answer (score 0):

`courier` table and `control` table is connected by `idcourier` and `courier` table and `messenger` table is also connected by `idcourier` but `messenger` table and `control` table are not connected at all. Another thing is `idcourier` alone can not be pk in `control` table as per its data. it has duplicate data.

```
select t1.idcourier,cnt,sm
from (
SELECT COURIER.IDCOURIER,
  COUNT(MESSENGER.IDMESSENGER) as cnt
FROM COURIER
left JOIN MESSENGER
ON COURIER.IDCOURIER = MESSENGER.IDCOURIER
GROUP BY COURIER.IDCOURIER ) t1
inner join (
SELECT COURIER.IDCOURIER,
  SUM(CONTRAL.MAXNUMBEROFMESSENGERS) as sm
FROM COURIER
left JOIN CONTRAL
ON COURIER.IDCOURIER = CONTRAL.IDCOURIER
GROUP BY COURIER.IDCOURIER )t2 on t1.idcourier = t2.idcourier;
```

Comment: add some description in your answer for explanation

Comment: courier table and control table is connected by idcourier and courier table and messenger table is also connected by idcourier but messenger table and control table are not connected at all. Another thing is idcourier alone can not be pk in control table as per its data. it has  duplicate data. so i did seperate joins on related tables and did inner join on the outcomes of two subqueries.